# Generate random key for a row with SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm loading a large amount of data with SQL Loader. 
The target table has a unique, system-generated PK.
When the table is populated by the business application, the key is generated programatically.
The extract file for the bulk upload doesn't have key in the record. 
Also, the upload is running in multiple threads, because of the extremely large volumes, and in stages - one file a day.
Is there way to populate a column with random key char(14), directly in SQL Loader? In other words, can I have something like that in the Control File:

```
ID EXPRESSION (random number creation expression), 
name char(10),
age number
```

so from the data file

```
Joe, 10
Mary, 5
```

I'll create data:

```
719287398 Joe  10
645743657 Mary 5
```

Comment: A *'random, non-sequential number'* is not appropriate for a primary key column. Is the application program unit which generates the key a database  function?

Comment: sorry, my bad. not number, a char, 14 digits.  I'll fix the question. The application does the key generation in java.

Comment: A random string is no better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `ID EXPRESSION "dbms_random.string('l',14)"` can be used.